# Problema al crear un instalador de un script que incluye vectores de llama-index y la API de OpenAI para embeddings

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Tengo un problema al crear el instalador de mi Chatbot, Chatne, estoy usando  **llama_index** y el **API de OpenAI** para crear **embeddings** y usar el modelo  gpt-3.5-turbo.

Tengo los siguientes errores:

- Error en tokenizer y get_encoding
- Archivo VERSION de llama-index no encontrado
- Archivo create_facts.txt de langchain no encontrado

```
C:\Users\userpc\source\repos\Chatne\dist\chatne>chatne
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatne.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "llama_index\embeddings\base.py", line 62, in __init__
  File "llama_index\utils.py", line 50, in tokenizer
  File "tiktoken\registry.py", line 60, in get_encoding
ValueError: Unknown encoding gpt2
[11772] Failed to execute script 'chatne' due to unhandled exception!

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\userpc\\source\\repos\\Chatne\\dist\\chatne\\langchain\\chains\\llm_summarization_checker\\prompts\\create_facts.txt'
[20160] Failed to execute script 'chatne' due to unhandled exception!


C:\Users\userpc\source\repos\Chatne\dist\chatne>chatne
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "llama_index\utils.py", line 50, in tokenizer
  File "tiktoken\registry.py", line 60, in get_encoding
ValueError: Unknown encoding gpt2
[11772] Failed to execute script 'chatne' due to unhandled exception!
```